# Python: `.to_html() function` to open a pandas dataframe in browser using `urllib.requests`

Tags: python, pandas

I have seen that there are many different versions of rendering html using Django or Flask, but is it possible to render html generated via python to display in a browser?
If so, can a browser be specified or is it the default system broswer?

I have code now that will give me a pandas data frame in html format (using `.to_html()`) but I need to have this opened in a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a module called webbrowser that does it

```
#!/usr/bin/python36

import webbrowser, os

with open(filename, "w") as f: f.write(html)

browser_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'

webbrowser.get(browser_path).open('file://' + os.path.realpath(filename))
```

Comment: I have tried this and it does't open the html in a browser, it just gives me truncated html printed to console: `<html><head><body><title>...</title><title>...</title><title>...</title></body></head></html>`

Comment: what is the content of the file? @swagless_monk

Comment: the file is some html that is generated using the `.to_html()` function from beautifulsoup. So the script generates some html and then I try using the method suggested and it gives the result from comments above

Comment: the problem is not with the browser, it is bs4 `to_html()` that truncates the html, try working with lxml. It is a parser problem @swagless_monk

Comment: I am limited to using `html.parser` bc of job network

Comment: okay, but since it is not a browser related problem I suggest you post another question the site. Otherwise people won't see it @swagless_monk

Comment: Hmm... I get what ya mean @Liam

Comment: feel free to write me a message if you need help @swagless_monk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184713/discussion-between-liam-and-swagless-monk).

Comment: The solution was to write `#!/usr/bin/python36` as the first line of the script. Then I had to call the script from the browser using the IP address of the RDP that I used to create the script